# using css display <button /> when cursor hovering over

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, less

Gratitude to everyone! I wanna implement a function in reactJS, the `<button />` concealed when page loading, and will display by hovering the cursor on it, I have tried many ways but still not fixed the problem yet. There're my codes down, thx every master.

```
.leftButton {
  margin-top: 290px;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  transition: 3s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #314561;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  //z-index: 10;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;

  &:hover {
   display: block;
  }
}

render() {
return <button className={styles.leftButton>
}
```

by then, I found somebody said use  label wrapping , I have tried, still not work

```
.father {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.leftButton:hover .father {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}


return(
 <div className={styles.father}>
    <button className={styles.leftButton} />
 </div>);
```

Comment: You can't use `:hover` on an element hidden with `display: none` since there is nothing to hover over. In your second attempt, the selector should be `.father:hover .leftButton { ... }`.

Comment: yeah, you're right, it's my fault, poor foundation of CSS ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to wrap your button, just use this css:

```
.leftButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
}

.leftButton:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

<button className={styles.leftButton} />
```